# Android native Web View not working flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am building a flutter app. I want to open webview from android native. I am calling the web using method channel. But when calling webview it showing error 
    `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.webkit.WebView.loadUrl(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference`

The code is shown below

***main.dart***

```
new RaisedButton(onPressed: ()async{
    final response=await channel.invokeMethod("WebView","");
        getRes(response);
    },
child:new Text("Go to Web View"))
```

and the java code is

***MainActivity.java***

```
public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
private WebView webview;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            new MethodChannel(getFlutterView(), CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler(
    new MethodCallHandler() {
        @Override

            if (methodCall.method.equals("WebView")){
                Log.d("LOG","Entered in WebView ");
                webview.loadUrl("https://www.journaldev.com"); // Error is showing on here
            }
    });

        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this);
        webview2 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_book1);

         }
    }
```

The error is showing in `webview.loadUrl("https://www.journaldev.com");` line

***web_view.xml***

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/web_book1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

How to open android native WebView in flutter view. How it possible?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to load an inline WebView inside the widget tree of your Flutter app or if you want to open an in-app browser, you can try my plugin [flutter_inappbrowser](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappbrowser) (**EDIT**: it has been renamed to [flutter_inappwebview](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview)).

An example is presented below (see the full example [here](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview/tree/master/example)):

```dart
...

child: InAppWebView(
  initialUrl: "https://flutter.dev/",
  initialHeaders: {},
  initialOptions: InAppWebViewWidgetOptions(
      inAppWebViewOptions: InAppWebViewOptions(
        debuggingEnabled: true,
      )
  ),
  onWebViewCreated: (InAppWebViewController controller) {
    webView = controller;
  },
  onLoadStart: (InAppWebViewController controller, String url) {

  },
  onLoadStop: (InAppWebViewController controller, String url) {

  },
),

...
```